# A function defined on a closed set such that $f \geq M$ reach a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I am wondering if the following is true :

> Let $f : C \to \mathbb{R}^p$ be a continuous function where $C$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover there is $M$ such that for all $x \in C, \|f(x)\| \geq M$. Then does $f$ reach a minimum ?

I know that this with the assumption $C$ is a compact set. Yet here $C$ is only closed. So if we denote $ \mu = \inf \{\|f(x)\| \mid x \in C\}$ then I need to find $\alpha \in C$ such that : $\|f(\alpha) \| = \mu$.

So there is a sequence $(\|f(x_n)\|)_n$ which converges to $\mu$. So there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\| f(x_n) \|$ converges to $\mu$. Yet the problem here is that the sequence $(x_n)$ might not converges...

Thank you !

Comment: $f$ can't reach a minimum nor maximum (at least for $p>1$), I think you mean if $||f||$ reaches it's minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

For example, the function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = \exp(x)$ is defined on a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ($\mathbb{R}$ itself), is continuous, is always greater than $0$, but it does not reach a minimum.

Moreover, notice that the asumption $||f(x)|| \geq M$ is useless because it is always true with $M=0$.

Comment: Nice catch about $\|f(x) \| \geq M$ being redundant! I suppose a better question would be to set $f:C \to \mathbb{R}$ and to let $f$ be bounded (for which of course our answers work the same).

Answer (score 0):

No. Choose $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto e^x$. It's bounded by $0$ but does not reach a minimum.